# ASP.Net Entity Framework and Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I am battling to work out how to handle foriegn keys with Entity Framework, when editing or adding a new record. For example, I have a person table, which has a timezone_id linking to my timezone table.

But the model seems to not include timezone_id. I see it's a new way of doing things, but ... how do I store my record?

My method:

```
 public static string CreateUser(string username, string email, string password, string firstname, string surname, int timezoneId)
    {
        user u = new user();
        u.surname = surname;
        u.firstname = firstname;
        u.email = email;
        u.password = password;
        u.username = username;
        Db.AddTousers(u);

        Db.SaveChanges();

        return username;

    }
```

I can't do u.timezone_id = timezoneid;

I only have u.timezone (which seems to be the actual entity), and u.timezoneReference, which I am not sure what to do with.

Comment: When talking about EF, the version(s) are rather important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to fill in the timezone entity from the database, i.e.

```
u.timezone = DB.TimezoneSet.FirstOrDefault(tz => tz.Id == timezoneid);
```

assuming you've generated the set name with EF3; it'll be `DB.Timezones` by default in EF4. If this is EF4 then you can also regenerate your EDMX for that table with ID columns included too - there's an option on the front page of the wizard.

The `TimezoneReference` property is used to test whether child entities have been loaded, force them to load, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I only have u.timezone

Yes, the model should expose a FK as a Navigation property. Just assign your TimeZone object there.

Comment: Thanks Henk - could you assist with that? How would I assign it? I thought I could do u.timezone_id = timezoneid; - but I can't. How do I assign a timezone object? My dropdown list only has a description and and id... So, I am passing the Id into the method (int).

Comment: You can use the Id to look up the TimeZone (from the context) or change the listbox to hold complete TimeZones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF v1, and you dont want to add the object as it is, you would need to do this.

```
u.TimezoneReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("DB.TimeZone", "ID", id)
```

id is the foreign key.

If you are using EF v4 and still not getting the forgeign keys exposed then I guess you did not check the option to generate foreign keys while creating the model.